# Reimer-Tiemann reaction on indole

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution, electrophilic-substitution, carbene

According to me net reaction should be at $\ce{C3}$ when Reimer-Tiemann reaction is done on indole (see image), since in the resonance structure, negative charge is on this carbon.

[image]

But, the answer given is on $\ce{C2}$, and the solution given is

> In pyrolle, the most electrophilic site is $\ce{C2}$. Think in a similar way.

But, I can't either find fallacy in my reasoning, not do I convince with the solution.

**TL;DR** Where will dichlorocarbene attack on indole (am not interested in ring expansion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper by Order and Lindwall [[1](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01178a006)] agrees with you that the R-T reaction gives indole-3-carboxaldehyde.

> Since its isolation in 1903 by Hopkins and Cole (1), 3-indole aldehyde has been investigated very little. It was first prepared by Ellinger (2) from indole through the use of the Reimer-Tiemann reaction. This method was improved on later by Boyd and Robson (3).

#### References

1. Order, R. B. V.; Lindwall, H. G. 3-Indole Aldehyde and Certain of Its Condensation Products. *J. Org. Chem.* **1945**, 10 (2), 128–133. DOI: [10.1021/jo01178a006](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01178a006).

Comment: What about the explanation given in the solution?

Comment: Indole is not pyrrole

Comment: Also note that the answer refers to C2 as "most electrophilic", which is true. But in the first step of the R-T reaction, the aromatic ring acts as a nucleophile, so the reaction happens at the most nucleophilic position (C3) rather than the electrophilic position (C2).